# question of yes or not in javascript discord

Tags: javascript

I was tryng to make a rock, paper, scissors game bot but i wanna ask if they wanna know the rules of the game enter image description here

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aovn9.png)

[here is what happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik7E7.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You're still accessing the same message object, which content will still always be 'k-PPT'.

Comment: @SteffenAndreasKloster and how can i change the accesing message?